# how would i find the average when using a 'while' loop in python using this code?

Tags: python, while-loop, average, mean

how would i find the average when using a 'while' loop in python using this code?

```
 n1 = int (input("Enter a value up 100, enter 0 when finished"))
 high =n1

while n1!=0:
     if n1 > high:
     high=n1
     n1 = int(input("Enter another number"))
```

this sections keeps telling the user to enter values, from here on i dont know how to work out the mean.

Comment: What have you tried? You presumably know how to calculate an average on paper?

Comment: i know how to work out the average, ive tried sum=n1/(i dont know what to add here) that is where i am confused, then print("this is your average", sum)

Comment: Well if you want to keep it up to date as you add in all the numbers, there are a few ways you can do it.

Comment: It would help to maintain the sum of the numbers entered, not the maximum value seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the `sum` and the `total_count`, and then you can compute the mean whenever you need to.

```
n1 = int (input("Enter a value up 100, enter 0 when finished"))
high = n1
total_count = 0
sum = 0

while n1 != 0:
    count += 1
    sum += n1
    if n1 > high:
        high=n1
    n1 = int(input("Enter another number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a counter variable in your while loop, that is:

```
while n1 != 0:
    loopCounter += 1
```

You would get the amount of numbers inputted, and you also need the total of all the numbers inputted, as you know. You could do a similar thing inside the loop:

```
while n1 != 0:
    total += n1
sum = total / loopCounter
print("Your average is",sum)
```